# JFileChooser filter for file names

Tags: java

I want my JFileChooser to only display directories and files that start with any variable, for example all files that start with `jgg300...`

I tried using `FileFilter` but it only works for files that have a file format like `bat` or `exe`, my files don't have a file format they are just files.

I tried using some solutions I found on google but they didn't work
Maybe I'm using FileFilter wrong but I can't get it to work.

edit:
I want to filter by the Start of the file not the end.

Comment: There should be a file with extension. Please check

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code that creates and configures your JFileChooser.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new FilenameFilter like so

```
String[] myFiles = directory.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
        return fileName.startsWith("jgg300");
    }
});
```

Comment: I already did that but it didnt work